# is there a tool which enhances the windows open/save file dialog to allow adding comments (descript.ion file)

Tags: windows

i am looking for a program/tool which allows to change the windows open/save dialog to allow adding comments which are then saved into a descript.ion file

[image]

example description file:

```
tumblr.jpg description for this file
"Server Error.png" another description
"We'll be back shortly.png" 3rd desc
monster.jpeg one more
```

Answer (score 1):

Total Commander.  Just select the files and then press Ctrl+Z (File | Edit Comment...).  I have used this program for more than 15 years.

http://ghisler.ch.

Comment: i know and use that already but in this case its about a shell extension, so i can use internet explorer or firefox file save dialogs to add comments which i can use in totalcommander