# Create comment for files in Windows (7)?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find a tag based file manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/78473/where-to-find-a-tag-based-file-manager)

How can I add a "comment" to **files** in Windows 7?

I can add comments to *folders* by using `Desktop.ini` (see [here](https://superuser.com/a/103312/140047)).

But how can I do same for files?

I saw these questions as well, but I could not use their answers:

- [Is there a windows program that will log a reason for copying a file to a folder?](https://superuser.com/q/103924/140047)
- [Is there a tool which enhances the windows open/save file dialog to allow adding comments (descript.ion file)](https://superuser.com/q/367063/140047)

Comment: Can you explain why you "could not usetheir answers"?

Comment: @DaveM I tried to install `HOBComment` and `Total Commander` but those did not work.

Comment: Total Commander works fine even in Windows 8.

Comment: @Karan Did you try it in win7?Or may be I did not install it correctly?

Comment: What happens when you try to install/run it? Do you get an error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to find a tag based file manager?](http://superuser.com/questions/78473/where-to-find-a-tag-based-file-manager) also see [What's good tagging software for Windows Explorer?](http://superuser.com/questions/109099/whats-good-tagging-software-for-windows-explorer)

Comment: @Karan I downloaded zip,extracted it,copy 2 files to another directory,double clicked install.bat .No error occured,but when I right click on a file,I do not see any option in about adding comment.

Comment: The 32/64-bit installers are all EXE files. Unless I missed something, the only ZIP-based package is for the 16-bit Windows 3.1 version. Once you have it installed, did you follow the answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/415701/138343), i.e. "press Ctrl+Z (File | Edit Comment...)" from within TC?

Comment: @Karan But I did not see any EXE file for it.Now I try to find it's EXE file in web.

Comment: @techie007 Thank you for your comment.It has very useful links.